# Symbol for excluding one element of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $x_i \in x := (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. I want to define $x_{-i}$ such that $x_{-i}$ contains every element of $x$ except $x_i$, i.e. $x_i \not \in x_{-i}:=(\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots)$.

- Is there some symbol like setminus, say $x_{-i}:= x \setminus x_i$?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was [Richard Rado](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Rado), author of many notational innovations, who introduced the so-called obliteration sign, a hat placed over an element of a sequence to indicate its deletion:

> $$(x_1,\dots,\hat x_i,\dots,x_n)=(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_n)$$

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any such notation, but you could define a crippling matrix:

$${\bf C}_{i} = \left[\begin{array}{lll}{\bf I}_{i-1}&0&0\\0 & 0 & {\bf I}_{n-i} \end{array}\right]$$

This matrix is an identity matrix which has had it's $i$th row removed and everything else intact so that if we multiply from the left:

$${\bf C}_i{\bf x}$$

then he first $i-1$ entries will be copied from $\bf x$ by the first identity matrix, then one skipped, and the remaining copied. This way you could use algebra with these matrices instead of having a need for adding notation on to the vectors themselves ( which usually just add a source of confusion anyway ).

---

**Edit**

${\bf C}_i$ assumes $\bf x$ is column, but it will of course work for row vectors ${\bf x}^T$ by doing the transpose:

$${\bf x}^T {{\bf C}_i}^T$$

---

**As an example**

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_5\\x_6\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: This will only reduce that component to zero; it won't remove the component entirely and reduce the dimension of the result.

Comment: Yes it will. I can give a concrete example.

Comment: You're correct, I appear to have misread a subscript. Apologies.